# In Excel-DNA adding a new line in context menu at right-click on a cell in a spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel-interop, excel-dna

I would to do the following in Excel-DNA :

for any workbook referencing the xll, in any sheet of the workbook, at the right click on a cell, the normal menu appears (with "cut", "copy", "paste") with a new line called "something", and when "something" is clicked on, it opens a "form" (taking for instance two number in input or anything).

Would that be impossible with Excel-DNA (I digged in Excel-DNA source code on github, I don't see anything related to context menus), I am willing to do it with Excel-Interop.

Answer (score 2):

For Excel 2010+, the context menus can be also customized in the ribbon
xml.

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/ customui">
<ribbon>
[.....]
</ribbon>
<contextMenus>
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">

<button idMso="FileSave" insertBeforeMso="Cut" />

<button id="MyButton" label="Toggle Case Upper/Lower/Proper" insertBeforeMso="Cut" onAction="ToggleCaseMacro" imageMso="HappyFace"/>

<menu id="MySubMenu" label="Case Menu" insertBeforeMso="Cut" >
<button id="Menu1Button1" label="Upper Case" imageMso="U" onAction="UpperMacro"/>
<button id="Menu1Button2" label="Lower Case" imageMso="L" onAction="LowerMacro"/>
<button id="Menu1Button3" label="Proper Case" imageMso="P" onAction="ProperMacro"/>
</menu>

<menuSeparator id="MySeparator" insertBeforeMso="Cut" />

</contextMenu>
</contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Comment: That's indeed perfect, thx a lot ! And doesn't cause NuGet packages problems in my production environment as my "solution" does (as there's no NuGet package for Microsoft.Office.Core). 
But your solution has one drawback if I am not mistaken : it doesn't seem possible to fetch a reference to the cell where the right-click took place. (What I typically want to do is : at the right-click, if the string in the Excel cell is the handle of an object in the XLL cache, then I take some action, for instance I trigger a windows forms displaying the object for it to be modified if needed etc.)

Comment: Maybe the cell where the right-click happens always becomes the selected cell (`Application.Selection`)?

Comment: Well yes I know, but I also don't know because I don't know where to write the `Application.Selection` code part. As I implemented what you advised directly inside the `.dna` file (which is the same as doing it in an xml), the only C sharp code I wrote the codes of function trigger by clicking on menu button. I don't have any code listen to a right-click event and responsible of triggering the standard (and altered by your solution) right-click excel menu ...

Comment: To be more precise, what I want to achieve doing is : at right click in a cell and click on MySubMenu and on Menu1Button2 or Menu1Button3, I trigger the display of a windows form that I used to construct (at the click on some button in the form) objects in the cache of the XLL, with a given hand, and I want to have this handle written in the cell in which I right-clicked. And at right click in a cell containg a string s and click on MySubMenu and on Menu1Button1, I want to see if the XLL cache there is an object with handle s, and if so, to display it in a windows form.

Answer (score 0):

I browsed to [Excel-DNA's source code on github](https://github.com/Excel-DNA) and came across the `IExcelAddIn` interface that I straightforwadly implemented in the following code that works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using ExcelDna.Integration.CustomUI;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;


namespace AddinThings
{
    public class MyAddin : IExcelAddIn
    {
        Application xlApp = (Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;

        private Office.CommandBar GetCellContextMenu()
        {
            return this.xlApp.CommandBars["Cell"];
        }

        void exampleMenuItemClick(Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Example Menu Item clicked");
        }

        void IExcelAddIn.AutoOpen()
        {
            Office.MsoControlType menuItem = Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton;
            Office.CommandBarButton exampleMenuItem = (Office.CommandBarButton)GetCellContextMenu().Controls.Add(menuItem, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);

            exampleMenuItem.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
            exampleMenuItem.Caption = "Example Menu Item";
            exampleMenuItem.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(exampleMenuItemClick);
        }

        private void ResetCellMenu()
        {
            GetCellContextMenu().Reset(); // reset the cell context menu back to the default
        }


        void IExcelAddIn.AutoClose()
        {
            ResetCellMenu();
        }
    }
}
```