# No Core (from Microsoft.Office.Core) in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel NuGet package

Tags: c#, office-interop, nuget-package, excel-interop, office-automation

In the context of the question

[In Excel-DNA adding a new line in context menu at right-click on a cell in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156192/in-excel-dna-adding-a-new-line-in-context-menu-at-right-click-on-a-cell-in-a-spr)

I need to use the `_Application.CommandBars` property from the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace -- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.commandbars?view=excel-pia.

I made my code work by adding reference to the Office.dll, but I was surprised that this was the only way for which `Core` from `Microsoft.Office.Core` was recognized, allowing me to use the `_Application.CommandBars` property.

Being in a development context where I am forced to reference NuGet packages rather than DLLs, I naturally tried to add the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Nuget package and add the following error :

```
The type 'CommandBars' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
```

telling in fact to reference the Office.dll rather than the NuGet package ... so that I am really stuck here.

Also, there is no Microsoft NuGet packages for `Microsoft.Office.Core`, even if there are non-Microsoft packages, maybe revealing that the problem I have is a known one.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using third-party NuGet packages you need to add COM references in Visual Studio on your own. Right click on the `References` of your project in the `Solution Explorer` window and choose the `Add Reference...` context menu item. On the dialog you will find the COM tab on the left-hand side where you can find all type libraries registered on the system. Find the required entries and then click the Ok button to add selected entries.

[image: COM references dialog in Visual Studio]

Comment: Removing all references to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and doing what you advise (and what I already tried but nevermind, I should have mentioned, I am sorry) leads to intellisense crying again on the `Core` bit of `Microsoft.Office.Core`. As if the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Core` is really not defined in any dll except the office.dll.

Comment: Search for the core entry in the list of type libraries.

Comment: Ok, but as said in my question, I am forced to used nuget packages.

Comment: Does it work if you add COM references manually? Could you confirm that?

Comment: Yes it does. In fact I already tried that myself on friday before asking the question, having as usual problems to locate the Office.dll in the COM type libs (I usually point directly to it, but at the end it points to the same DLL). Then I coded everything fine, and then switched back the real issue which is me being forced to used NuGet packages as mentioned in the question.

Comment: In that case you need to ask the NuGet creator to include the missing assembly or just create your own NuGet package if it is really required (you are forced to).

Comment: The second option would be the easier one, up to having to check compatibility between my Microsoft.Office.Core NuGet package and the excel interop's one. The first one is impossible. MS won't provide that NuGet as it presupposes people having office installed hence having the DLL.